# The parameter 'padding' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

hope u guys doing well..

so, Earlier i'm Following Flutter Tutorial On Youtube, and looks like there's no problems with his BorderBox Class, but mine is different, it have 3 problems cause of padding, width, height, are null.

```
class BorderBox extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final double width, height;

  const BorderBox({Key? key,
    this.padding,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.child}) : super(key: key);
```

with the error message below

> The parameter 'padding' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

> The parameter 'width' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

> The parameter 'height' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

is there a way too bypass the null Parameters??
also this is the video i followed the tutorial on youtube [Here](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxejIvKUQvwigM4pQWTB0QZCNpAxDSWjWx)

Thank You, and have a good day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `required` in the constructor for non-nullable values like so:

```
  const BorderBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.padding,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.child,
   }) : super(key: key);
```

However, if you don't want them to be required, you can make them nullable like so:

```
class BorderBox extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final double? width, height;

  const BorderBox({
    Key? key,
    this.padding,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

The ? means that the variable can be null, which gives you the ability to not make it required.

You can read more on null safety here: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: i already use that, but it makes everytime i make some children in Other Class that need BorderBox,, there's problems that Parameters Padding Are Required.

EDIT : Let me try the below one.